# How to use Process Class to execute commands need to enter password in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to execute commands below by Process Class:

```
let uninstallTask = Process()
        uninstallTask.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
//MarkerPro is an app in launchpad
        uninstallTask.arguments = ["-c","sudo rm -rf "+"/Applications/MarkerPro.app"]
        uninstallTask.launch()
```

But get errors below:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

So probably need to enter password before i execute delete command.

Comment: This is not the right way to go about it. For one, as the error says, a GUI application doesn't have a TTY terminal over which the password could be entered. Secondly, even if it did, that's a terrible user experience and would raise lots of alarms. Instead, use Authorization services to create a helper service that runs with escalated permissions, and use it to directly delete the file via the `FileManager` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using "STPrivilegedTask" which is a tool to get authorization by users.
Using FileManager API I think also a good idea